# Recuperar imagens com scandir do PHP e imprimir incrementando de acordo com o número de ocorrências

Tags: php

Preciso recuperar imagens de uma pasta e só tenho o número de referência gravado no banco de dados. Também tenho que criar um incremento, pois pra cada referência pode ter n imagens.

Combinando as funções *scandir* e *strstr* do *PHP* consigo recuperar, mas apesar de imprimir corretamente o que preciso, no caso as 6 imagens como no exemplo 1  *"$domain"*, ela não filtra os outros resultados, dificultando criar o incremento correto, tipo foto-1- ... foto-2- ... etc.

Acrescentando a quebra de linha se percebe os outros resultados ocultos, fazendo o incremento pegar todos resultados da pasta. Agradeço qualquer solução.

As imagens são salvas assim: Ex: foto-1-0023.jpg, foto-2-0023.jpg

```
$dir    = '../assets/Imagens/';
$files = scandir($dir);


foreach ($files as $key => $value) :
    $conta=1;
    //$domain = strstr($value, "foto-".$conta++."-".$row['referencia']);
    // Exemplo 1

    $domain = strstr($value,  $row['referencia']);

    echo $domain ; 
    // imprime 00234.jpg00234.jpg00234.jpg00234.jpg00234.jpg00234.jpg (6 imagens)

    echo $domain.'<br>' ; 
    //imprime 00234.jpg


    //00234.jpg
    //00234.jpg



    //00234.jpg
    //00234.jpg
    //00234.jpg

endforeach;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Obrigado pela sugestão Daniel, mais acabei resolvendo de outra forma. Não é a mais elegante porém funcionou tanto para imprimir, quanto para alterar os arquivos.

```
<?php
    //select para obter a referencia

    $d=0;
    $m=0;                    

    //loop para buscar as imagens foto-1, foto-2, ...
    for ($i=0; $i<99; $i++) :
        $fotopasta ="assets/Imagens/foto-".++$m."-" .$row['referencia'] .".jpg";

        //se a imagem existir insere no array
        if(file_exists($fotopasta)) :
            $fotopastaArray[] = $fotopasta;
        endif;
    endfor;

    //percorro a string e descubro o numero da ultima imagem
    $qtd_fotos = substr(end($fotopastaArray), 20,2);

    //monto outro loop com o numero correto de ocorrencia
    for ($n=0; $n < $qtd_fotos; $n++) :
        $foto ="assets/Imagens/foto-".++$d."-".$row['referencia'].".jpg"; ?>
        <?php if (file_exists($foto)) :  ?>
            <li><img src="<?php echo $foto ; ?>" alt="<?php echo utf8_encode($row['nome']) ; ?>"></li>
        <?php else : endif;  
    endfor; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode facilitar salvando o caminho parcial no banco e evitando um loop em pasta que é mais custoso pro código executar, salva "/assets/Imagens/image001.jpg" no banco e recupera com um:

"http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. $row['img_url']"

sendo o $row a array que virá do loop no banco.

Caso seja inviável, posso te ajudar a pensar na mesma linha que você está fazendo no momento.

Comment: Ok obrigado @Daneil Costa, estou fazendo testes e assim que poder nós continuamos.